# jquery 1.4 Live behaviour on .each?

Tags: jquery, live, jquery-1.4

Does jQuery allow us to use .each loops for live elements?

I'm creating radio buttons on the fly and need to loop over all of them, but the .each loop doesn't seem to work on live elements.

If jquery is not supporting this kind of live looping, is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: `.live()` doesn't work this way, it attaches handlers up at the document level and listens for when events bubble up.  A new element, old element, it doesn't matter...they all bubble events the same way.

The common misconception is that `.live()` attach events as elements are added...this isn't the case.  Just because of how it works, `.each()` can't be used in this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`live()` only works for event binding. The only thing that comes to my mind is to put all code in a function an execute it again after you inserted the elements.

Answer (score 0):

at the end of the loop, initialise the radio buttons.

it worked for me.